# Query database for most current message per receiver_id

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Here is example of my mysql query problem:

```
Table name: messaging
Id   ad_id  sender_id    receiver_id    message
1    2      5            1              message1
2    2      5            1              message2
3    2      5            1              message3
4    8      7            3              message4
5    2      4            2              message5
```

Now i would like to run a mysql query which will output results in following format:

```
Id   ad_id  sender_id    receiver_id    message
3    2      5            1              message3
4    8      7            3              message4
5    2      4            2              message5
```

Note: multiple rows with the same value in ad_id, sender_id and receiver_id should output only the last row.

I would appreciate any assistance to achieve similar output. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share the code you already tried?

Comment: *last row* without a time stamp or a date column in the table is meaningless.

Comment: Yes i also have column date_sent and date_read and here is the code i just tried now but shoot me with  and error: SELECT MAX(Id) as Id, ad_id, sender_id, receiver_id FROM messaging GROUP BY ad_id, sender_id, receiver_id

Comment: <b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use GROUP BY with the 3 columns you want to agroup and then use the MAX to get the last inserted row of each group (assuming the Id is auto-increment)

```
SELECT MAX(Id) as Id, ad_id, sender_id, receiver_id FROM messaging GROUP BY ad_id, sender_id, receiver_id;
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help but i just tried this code but i got the following error: Warning:  mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given...

Comment: execute my sql code directly on your database (in phpmyadmin if you use it). It works the way you want. The warning that you are receiving its another problem, related to your php code.

Comment: Thanks, i really appreciate. I was able to detect the problem within the phpmyadmin but still trying resolve it within my php code.

Comment: :) create another question about your php code. and mark this one as resolved

Comment: I fixed my php code, but i tried adding WHERE clause on the query but i am getting an error. Please see here: SELECT MAX(id) AS id, ad_id, sender_id, reciever_id, message, status, date_sent FROM messaging WHERE reciever_id='$userID' GROUP BY ad_id, sender_id, reciever_id

Comment: you need to post the error message too

Comment: Thanks, i really appreciate. All set.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest shortlisting the correct Ids before extracting the data, especially if you have more columns.

```
select Id,  ad_id,  sender_id,  receiver_id,    message 
from messaging
where id in (select max(id)
        from messaging
        group by ad_id, sender_id,  receiver_id)
```